# probability that a number defined by a random process is irrational

Tags: irrational-numbers

What if we write $0$. and then throw a coin and depending on the result continue the number with 1 or $0$ and continue this process indefinitely.

It is clear that the result of this procedure is a real number. There is an infinity of infinite sequences of $0s$ and $1s$ that are rational (for example $0.101010...,0.101101101...$) I have also come to the conclusion that every infinite sequence (rational or irrational) has probability $0$.

My question is: What is the probability that the number produced is irrational? Or is it the case that like with the question: what is the probability that a number is prime, we cannot meaningfully assign a probability?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your probability measure is actually equivalent to the standard Lebesgue measure on the real line.

The probability of getting a rational number is zero, and the probability it is irrational is one.

Comment: I thought so, but thanks for confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean "depending on the result"?
Would you stop the process
or just write down the result?

Generalizing the answer of Stephen Montgomery-Smith 
(who is a much better mathematician than I),
the probability that the result
is transcendental or normal
or confused or traumatic
is also one.

The probability that
I am normal
is much closer to zero,
although I am not sure
about many aspects of
the process that created me
(certain aspects *are* well-known
and common to many others).

Comment: I mean that whether I continue the number with 0 or 1 depends on the result of my coin toss.

Comment: I dont understand the rest of the answer. Never heard of confused or traumatic numbers.

Comment: 1) How does it depend on the result of the coin toss?

2) Joke.